# Java Dead Code, can someone explain?

Tags: java, dead-code

This is part of a binary tree class, here is the find function, given the key to find the node in the tree, if not found return `null`, however this part have been recognized as dead code, when I move the `if(current==null)` statement to the bottom of inside `while` loop, it works, why? is it the same?

```
public class Tree {
    public Node root;

    public Node find(int key) {
        Node current = root;
        while (current.key != key) {
            if (current == null) { //dead code here, why?
                return null;
            }

            if (key < current.key) {
                current = current.leftChild;
            } else if (key > current.key) {
                current = current.rightChild;
            }
        }
        return current;
    }
}

public class Node {
    public char label;
    public boolean visited = false;
    public int key;
    public float data;

    public Node leftChild;
    public Node rightChild;

}
```

Comment: What is `root`? Where did you define it?

Comment: you never defined `root`, so `current` is ALWAYS null...

Comment: @MarcB in your case, it gives error. I think albert initialized root.

Comment: sorry, I have updated the entire code, the root is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `current` is `null` it will never reach to the null check as you are accessing `current.key` beforehand it will throw a `nullPointerException`
If you move the `if(current==null)` to bottom as you are assigning new value before it won't be a dead code. (as the current.leftChild and `current.rightChild` might be `null`)

Answer (score 1):

Because

```
while (current.key != key) // <-- current.key would throw NPE if current was null.
```

Answer (score 1):

On the statement before, you're dereferencing `current.key`.  If `current == null`, you will have an NPE.  If it is *not* `null`, then the `if` check is meaningless since it will never be reached.

What you probably intended to do was move the `if` check to before the loop instead:

```
public Node find(int key) {
    if (root == null) { 
        return null;
    }
    Node current = root;
    while (current.key != key) {
        if (key < current.key) {
            current = current.leftChild;
        } else if (key > current.key) {
            current = current.rightChild;
        }
    }
    return current;
}
```

This would give you the intended behavior that you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (current.key != key) {
        if (current == null) { //dead code here, why?
            return null;
        }
```

in your while condition you are already making sure that current is not null (by using current.key!=key) , so there's no point in rechecking it in if(current==null). if current=null, then you will get a NullPointerException in your while() and you will not even reach the if condition.

Answer (score 0):

If current.key has not already thrown a NullPointerException through the attempt to access the key member, current cannot possibly be null at the beginning of the while loop. When the test is moved to the bottom of the loop, current has been assigned a new value which the compiler recognizes as potentially null.